# Who can I make the image in my tweet click able?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I have a simple tweepy script that post an image. I'd like for users to click on the image and go to a URL I specify.

I could do this ...

```
import tweepy

... auth stuff ...
api = tweepy.API(auth)

str1 = "blah blah blah click here: http://example.com/cute_puppy"
r = api.update_with_media('cutepuppy.png', status=str1)
```

... but I'd prefer if my twitter followers could just click on the image.

```
import tweepy

... auth stuff ...
api = tweepy.API(auth)

str1 = "blah blah blah click on the cute puppy pic!"
r = api.update_with_media('cutepuppy.png', status=str1)
```

... but I do not know how to make the media `cutepuppy.png` behave like a link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. Twitter doesn't support that, either for posts made on their site or through their API -- clicking on a media object attached to a tweet will always view that object.

What you can do, however, is share a link to a site that has Twitter Cards set up to provide an image related to the link. Refer to Twitter's [Twitter Cards documentation](https://dev.twitter.com/cards/overview) for details.